# SASS | Indent based syntax in VS 2015

Tags: syntax, sass, visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know how I can use the SASS Indent based syntax in visual studio 2015 with highlighting.

I am not too fussed about compilation because I am using grunt for this anyway.

I am trying to get the company I work for to switch towards SASS indent syntax from LESS and so far everything looks as if I am winning in doing so.

The only issue is I think they will just scrap it off if I cant supply a way of using the syntax in VS2015 properly

anyone know any plugins etc?

thanks in advance,

Kieran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: do the following

tools > options > text editor > sass > tabs

check "smart"
choose the tab size
check "insert spaces"

This will give you the automatic indenting that you can get from CTRL + D to format your document.

As far as Highlighting intellisense, this should have been featured in your VS2015, but if it's not, Go to Extensions and Updates and search for "[SassyStudio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d)". This has intellisense in it

Here is another [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/robinbentley.sass-indented) for .sass files syntax highlight. I was able to use this with no internet connection workstations (government). I think this will help

Comment: The OP is asking about getting syntax highlighting for the less popular SASS (indented) syntax, not about how to control the indentation settings for the more popular SCSS syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I just updated the answer. caught it last minute.

Comment: @LOTUSMS Added SassyStudio but not syntax highlighting for SASS indent syntax (.SASS) files. just plain text. its only coming up with SCSS in text editor no SASS TAB either

Comment: I added another link to my answer that I had forgotten about. I think that's what you need. It worked for me before for .sass files

Comment: @LOTUSMS, sassy studio doesn't support vs2015.